# Kali 2021.1 can not find available wifi networks on virtualbox

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

Kali Linux 2021.1 could not find any WIFI networks near me but my host machine does. I am using RAlink 5370 chipset WIFI adapter. I can put this adapter in monitor mode but I could not see any BSSID in airodump-ng.

I have tried:

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') \
                linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') \
                broadcom-sta-dkms 
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

but this did not help. I am using USB port 2.0 and bridged connection but it did not help me either.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

`iwconfig`:

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any 
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=20 dBm 
Retry short long limit:2 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off 
Power Management:off
```

Thank you for giving your time.

Comment: Usually, the only network connection inside virtualbox is the bridge. There is no direct access to the hardware and therefore no way to connect to a network card. It may be possible to give the USB device to the virtualbox OS but the host OS will lose its network connection. I recommend you to forget about this possibility as it is full of problems and most probably it won't work correctly.

Comment: How do you map the host's WiFi adapter to the VM? On the VM, is the adapter visible in the output of `lsusb` and/or `ip a` and/or `iwconfig`? Do you see any kernel messages that refer to the adapter?

Comment: print out `iwconfig`

Comment: The name of the adapter is in lsusb and in iwconfig. Here are its output respectively.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: Please add such text to the question. The format in comments makes it very difficult to read it. Was that command run **inside** the VM or on the host ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the chipset of wifi adapter. I checked it in Parrot OS but it failed to detect Wifi networks. After going through Amazon reviews I got to know that many people are facing same problem. If anybody is going to buy Leoxsys LEO-HG150N 150Mbps Wireless USB Wi-Fi, I would not recommend buy it. 
Thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

Based on Debian Wiki the wireless firmware is included in [firmware-misc-nonfree](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/rt2800usb). In Kali Linux the package is provided by the [`firmware-nonfree`](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/firmware-nonfree)

Unload the `wl` it is not the correct module driver:

```
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo apt purge broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Install the require package:

```
sudo apt install firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: I have unloaded wl and all the drivers are already up to date. Still I can not see available wifi networks near me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem.
For me, a edit `NetworkManager.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

... and changed the `ifupdown` to true:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

These way my wifi adapter found all networks...